# Urn Problem: randomly pick a ball and replace the ball with different colour

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

An urn contains 5 black or white balls. At time 0, all the balls are white. At each step, we pick a ball uniformly in the urn, remove it and replace it with a ball of the opposite colour. Let $B_n$ be the number of black balls at time $n$.

1. Compute the long-run fraction of time where $B_n$=3
2. What is the expected value of the first time where the urn contains 5 white balls again?
3. Is it true that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(B_n=3)$ exists?

For 1, I want to use time reversibility. But I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

For 2, I think I've got it using one-step analysis.

For 3, I'm not sure how do proceed, since I'm not even sure about 1.

Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a random walk on the $5$-dimensional hypercube, with edges between adjacent vertices. A random walk on a connected graph spends equal proportion of time on each edge, and thus the proportion of time spent on a vertex is proportional to its degree. Here all $2^5=32$ vertices have the same degree, so the proportion of time on each vertex is $\frac1{32}$. Since $\binom53=10$ vertices correspond to $B_n=3$, the proportion of time where $B_n=3$ is $\frac{10}{32}=\frac5{16}$.

For $2$, you don’t need any further analysis. Since the proportion of time where all $5$ balls are white is $\frac1{32}$, the expected return time from $5$ white balls back to $5$ white balls is $32$.

For $3$, the limit doesn’t exist because $B_n=3$ can obtain only for odd $n$; in fact we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(B_{2n+1}=3)=\frac5{8}$ and $P(B_{2n}=3)=0$ (no limit required on the second one).

Comment: Very interesting!  How are the vertices of the hypercube defined?

Comment: Thank you! Just wondering, is there a way of using time reversibility to solve 1?

Comment: @mjw: They are $[0,1]^5$, e.g. with each entry $0$ for a white ball and $1$ for a black ball. (We can imagine the balls to have continuous identities that they pass on when they get replaced by an opposite-colour ball, so we can associate each ball with one component.)

Comment: @joriki, Nice!  Thank you very much!

Comment: @circleli: I don't know of one.

Comment: The proof of the claim “ A random walk on a connected graph spends equal proportion of time on each edge, and thus the proportion of time spent on a vertex is proportional to its degree“ typically is done via showing that this satisfies the detailed balance equations, i.e. making use of time reversibility.

Comment: @user8675309 Thank you!!

Comment: @ joriki, how did you get $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P(B_{2n+1=3} = 3)=\frac {5}{8}$? Thank you!

Comment: Btw I think a more standard solution is to recognize this is a birth-death chain... said chains have well known closed form steady states but you can also easily solve them from scratch via detailed balance equations e.g. what I did here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3496801/finding-the-stationary-distribution-for-this-discrete-time-markov-chain-dtmc/3496830#3496830

Comment: @circleli: See e.g. [this Wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Steady-state_analysis_and_limiting_distributions). This Markov chain has period $2$. Thus it has a separate limiting distribution for $B_{2n}$ and for $B_{2n+1}$. We have $P(B_{2n}=3)=0$ and thus $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(B_{2n}=3)=0$. In the stationary distribution, $\pi_3=\frac5{16}$ (from part $1$). The stationary distribution is the average of the two limiting distributions for $B_{2n}$ and $B_{2n+1}$. So $\frac12\left(0+\lim_{n\to\infty}P(B_{2n}=3)\right)=\frac5{16}$, and thus $P(B_{2n}=3)=\frac58$.